# I cannot attach drawer navigation menu to hamburger menu in Android after replacing it - using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I am new to Kotlin and relatively inexperienced with Android, I fixed a lot of issues with what I am doing but now I am really stuck.

So - the application's drawer menu works fine when I start the app, opening both when sliding it out of the side and when clicking on the hamburger icon.

I have two menus, one for when the app starts, the other one with different items presented to the the user after a successful login.

So far I have managed to replace the menu, link its items to the correct fragments, stop the hamburger from becoming an arrow for back navigation.

Now everything is working correctly apart from the hamburger menu not opening the drawer.

What is missing from the file in which I reassign the new menu? If it makes sense mentioning, the login happens uses retrofit, so `withContext ( Dispatchers.Main )` is to bring that part of code back to the UI thread ( or at least that's what I did to make it work with the UI ).

```
suspend fun selectMenu ( activity : AppCompatActivity, screenElements : MenuUtilScreenElementsWrapper )
{
    withContext ( Dispatchers.Main )
    {
        screenElements.navigationView.menu.clear()

        val navController              = activity.findNavController ( R.id.nav_host_fragment  )
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = activity.findViewById      ( R.id.drawer_layout      )
        val navView: NavigationView    = activity.findViewById      ( R.id.nav_view           )

        if ( screenElements.menuToUse == EnvironmentConstants.CHANGE_MENU_TO_PUBLIC )
        {
            var appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration (
                setOf
                    (
                        R.id.nav_login, R.id.nav_register, R.id.nav_about, R.id.nav_terms_and_conditions, R.id.nav_privacy
                    ), drawerLayout
            )
            activity.setupActionBarWithNavController           ( navController, appBarConfiguration )
            navView.setupWithNavController                     ( navController                      )

            screenElements.navigationView.inflateMenu ( R.menu.activity_public_drawer  )
            screenElements.navController.setGraph     ( R.navigation.public_navigation )
        }
        else
        {
            var appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration (
                setOf
                    (
                        R.id.nav_decks, R.id.nav_flashcards, R.id.nav_search
                ), drawerLayout
            )
            activity.setupActionBarWithNavController           ( navController, appBarConfiguration )
            navView.setupWithNavController                     ( navController                      )

            screenElements.navigationView.inflateMenu ( R.menu.activity_members_drawer  )
            screenElements.navController.setGraph     ( R.navigation.members_navigation )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to replace the menu and I just divided the two sets of menu items in two groups and hide / show them alternatively ( pre login vs post login "links" to activities )